# Golang API Gorilla MySQL query

Tags: mysql, api, go, gorilla, mux

So... I'm finally doing my side project containing the super nerdy tabletop game Warhammer in which I've created a database MySQL and my next step is to create a API.

I've got three tables at this moment... "tyranids", "greyknghts" and "deathguard". I want to make a dynamic query to select targeted table. I'm able to do this but as the tables grown I need to make this dynamic.

```
func getTyranids(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")

var units []Unit

result, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM tyranids")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error)
}

defer result.Close()

for result.Next() {
    var unit Unit
    err := result.Scan(&unit.ID, &unit.Name, &unit.Type, &unit.Movement, &unit.WeaponsSkill, &unit.BallisticSkill, &unit.Strength, &unit.Toughness, &unit.Wounds, &unit.Attacks, &unit.Leadership, &unit.Initiate, &unit.Points)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error)
    }
    units = append(units, unit)
}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(units)
```

}

How can I write this so I won't need a function for each table?

I've made it work with mux.Vars for each individual unit.

```
func getTyranidUnit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

params := mux.Vars(r)

result, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM tyranids WHERE name = ?", params["name"])
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer result.Close()

var unit Unit

for result.Next() {
    err := result.Scan(&unit.ID, &unit.Name, &unit.Type, &unit.Movement, &unit.WeaponsSkill, &unit.BallisticSkill, &unit.Strength, &unit.Toughness, &unit.Wounds, &unit.Attacks, &unit.Leadership, &unit.Initiate, &unit.Points)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(unit)
```

}

```
func main() {

db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "xx:xx@tcp(xxx)/Warhammer")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

defer db.Close()

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

router.HandleFunc("/tyranids", getTyranids).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/tyranids/{name}", getTyranidUnit).Methods("GET")    

http.ListenAndServe(":8001", router)
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a [map](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) to pair the tables to keys:

```
speciesUnitMap:= map[string]string{
    "Norn-Queen": "tyranids",
    "Hive Tyrant": "tyranids",
    "Rippers ": "tyranids",
    "Hive Ship": "tyranids",
‎    "Ork Boyz": "orcs",
    "‎Waaagh!": "orcs",
‎    "Warboss": "orcs",
    "‎Blood Axes" "orcs",

}


// This is dirty I would construct the string before 
// and do verifications that the received param is conform
result, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM " + 
       speciesUnitMap[params["name"]] + " WHERE name = ?", params["name"])
```